# Is a complex number whose real and imaginary parts are both transcendental transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a$ and $b$ are real and transcendental (over $\mathbb Q$), does it follow that $a+bi$ is also transcendental? I tried looking for a counterexample, but I don't actually know of many transcendental numbers besides $e$ and $\pi$, and I can't tell if, say, $e+i\pi$ is algebraic. Thus, I'm assuming that the statement is true, but is it? And how to prove it?

Also, what if $a$ is transcendental and $b$ is algebraic. Must $a+bi$ be transcendental?

Comment: If $z=a+bi$ were algebraic, then so would $\overline{z}=a-bi$. Then as a sum/difference of two algebraics, the numbers
$$a=\frac{z+\overline{z}}2,\qquad b=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$$ would also be algebraic.

Comment: For the second question, if $z=a+bi$ is algebraic and $b$ is algebraic, then $a=z-i\cdot b$ is also algebraic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been answered by Jyrki Lahtonen and Hagen von Eitzen in the comments.

> If $z=a+bi$ were algebraic, then so would $\bar z=a-bi$. Then as a sum/difference of two algebraics, the numbers
>   $$a=\frac{z+\bar z}2, \qquad b=\frac{z-\bar z}{2i}$$
>   would also be algebraic.

– [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789418/is-a-complex-number-whose-real-and-imaginary-parts-are-both-transcendental-trans#comment1635075_789418)

> For the second question, if $z=a+bi$ is algebraic and $b$ is algebraic, then $a=z-i\cdot b$ is also algebraic.

– [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789418/is-a-complex-number-whose-real-and-imaginary-parts-are-both-transcendental-trans#comment1635080_789418)